# R: How to assign a vector to a list of lists (with an index)

Tags: arrays, r, list, vector, variable-assignment

I am currently trying to create a list of lists, with the following initialization procedure.

```
df = data.frame(
    memberA = rep(0, m),
    memberB = rep(0, m)
  )
```

where I want to do assignment in the following manner. (I use `i` because i terate over multiple `i=1..m`).

```
df[i, "memberA"] = assignVector
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, "memberA", value = c(-1.6950557554083,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 1
```

What I am trying to achieve is to assign a vector to `df[i, "memberA"]`.

I very much assume that I have not enough column vectors (because `memberA` is a list of scalar). So I tried out the following (changing initialization):

```
df = data.frame(
    memberA = rep(0, m, n),
    memberB = rep(0, m, n)
  )
```

However, this does not seem to be the proper R way. Any idea on how to achieve what I want to achieve? I just want to assign the vector (for each `i=1..m`) to the respective matrix.

Comment: @Julius thx for the swift response! Edited the question :) What I am basically trying to achieve, is to assign a vector to `df[i, "memberA"]`. How do I have to change the initialization, such that I can account for vector assignments (i.e. doing this: `df[i, "memberA"] = assignVector` where `assignVector` is a vector).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use an object that easily lets you have columns that are lists. A good option is a `tibble`, which natively supports "list-columns".

```
library(tibble) # usually I would use library(tidyverse) which loads more useful packages
```

Then you need to initialize list-columns rather than plain vectors.

```
m <- 42
df <-  data_frame(
  memberA = vector("list", m),
  memberB = vector("list", m)
)
```

Next, the object `df[1, "memberA"]` isn't what you think it is, and you can't assign a vector to this. What you need is `df$memberA[[1]]` (or `df[[1, "memberA"]]`). These work:

```
df$memberA[[1]] <- 1:3
df[[3, "memberB"]] <- 42:69
```

Comment: As a side note, all of this works fine with an ordinary old `data.frame` too - `df <-  data.frame(memberA = I(vector("list", m)), memberB = I(vector("list", m)))`